# BLOB loading Oracle - ORA-22288

Tags: oracle, blob

**Purpose:** I want to load blob data types into an oracle table. (I don't want to use `sqlldr`).

**Error:**  `ORA-22288: file or LOB operation FILEOPEN failed`

**Src code:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY BLOB_DIR AS 'C:\';
CREATE TABLE tab1 (
  id        NUMBER,
  blob_data BLOB
);

DECLARE
  l_bfile  BFILE;
  l_blob   BLOB;

  l_dest_offset INTEGER := 1;
  l_src_offset  INTEGER := 1;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO tab1 (id, blob_data)
  VALUES (1, empty_blob())
  RETURN blob_data INTO l_blob;

  l_bfile := BFILENAME('BLOB_DIR', 'MyImage.gif');
  DBMS_LOB.fileopen(l_bfile, DBMS_LOB.file_readonly);
  -- loadfromfile deprecated.
  -- DBMS_LOB.loadfromfile(l_blob, l_bfile, DBMS_LOB.getlength(l_bfile));
  DBMS_LOB.loadblobfromfile (
    dest_lob    => l_blob,
    src_bfile   => l_bfile,
    amount      => DBMS_LOB.lobmaxsize,
    dest_offset => l_dest_offset,
    src_offset  => l_src_offset);
  DBMS_LOB.fileclose(l_bfile);

  COMMIT;
END;
```

**Additional Info:** I have a file with the following filepath - `C:\MyImage.gif` that I am trying to load. (Ideally I want to load a bunch but I am starting with one)

I'm using the following guide but I keep running into problems ([https://oracle-base.com/articles/8i/import-blob#:~:text=CREATE%20OR%20REPLACE%20DIRECTORY%20BLOB_DIR,insert%20it%20into%20the%20table.](https://oracle-base.com/articles/8i/import-blob#:%7E:text=CREATE%20OR%20REPLACE%20DIRECTORY%20BLOB_DIR,insert%20it%20into%20the%20table.))

Comment: The operating system directory - `C:\` in this case - has to be on the Oracle database server (all nodes if it's RAC). Is that the case, or are you trying to load a file from your local PC into a remove database, on a separate box? Also, was that the full error message? (There's a bit more info [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60506251/266304); the second half, anyway...)

Comment: Yeah the database is hosted in a docker container...I learned that files have to be server side for this sort of loading but I'm having trouble configuring that